# Request explanation of use of [[1, 2]]

Tags: functions, expression-manipulation

The following is the code for Kronig-Penney model from the book *A Physicist's Guide to Mathematica* by Patrick T. Tam. I would be grateful if someone could explain the code to me, especially line with `FindRoot`.
What is the role of `[[1, 2]]` there?

```
kmPlot[l_?Positive, nb_Integer?Positive, mp_Integer /; mp > 10] :=
  Module[{K, Q, d, r},
   K[n_, 1] := n*Pi;
   Q[n_, m_] := n*Pi - (m - 1)*Pi/(mp - 1);
   K[n_, m_] :=  
     K[n, m] = 
       FindRoot[Cos[Q[n, m]] == Cos[x] + (l/2)*(Sin[x]/x), {x,K[n, m - 1]}][[1, 2]];
   d[n_, m_] := K[n, m]^2;
   r[n_] := r[n] = Table[{Q[n, m], d[n, m]}, {m, 1, mp}];
   Graphics[
     Flatten[Table[{Line[r[n]], Line[{-#[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ r[n]]}, {n,1, nb}]], 
     Ticks ->  {Table[{I*Pi, I "p"}, {I, -nb, nb}], Automatic}, 
     Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"q(1/a)", "E"}, 
     AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]];
```

Comment: [Common pitfalls](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/5478) / What the @#%^&*?! do all those funny signs mean? / Other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy, given Mathematica's highly interactive nature, to answer questions like this yourself by making some simple experiments.

First it is alway good to look at strange notation with `FullForm`, which will shows you the internal form. `Hold` is used here to suppress evaluation of the form. This tells you that you should consult `Part` in the documentation.

```
 Hold[x[[1, 2]]] // FullForm
```

> `Hold[Part[x, 1, 2]]`

Next compare what `FindRoot` produces with and without `[[1, 2]]`.

```
 FindRoot[Sin[x] == x/2, {x, 2}]
```

> `{x -> 1.89549}`

```
 FindRoot[Sin[x] == x/2, {x, 2}][[1, 2]]
```

> `1.89549`

So you see that `[[1, 2]]` is used to extract the value of the root from the expression returned by `FindRoot`.

Comment: Just to note, `x /. FindRoot[Sin[x] == x/2, {x, 2}]` would be a more transparent way to achieve the same goal.

Comment: Thanks a lot m_goldberg. I did not know about Hold.Thanks a lot.